# ¿Qué es Firmar el Manifiesto de Click Once en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

Intento hacer un `Instalador` en la parte de **propiedades** y **publicar**, pero al intentar publicar me dice que tengo que agregar las firmas, pero quiero saber para que son esas Firmas, porque si no lo firmo no me deja Publicar. Y al ver en los Detalles de la Firma, me sale que es valido por un solo día, ¿se puede cambiar la fecha?

¿Qué finalidad tiene agregar esas `firmas`?

Gracias por sus respuestas, espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Para que usted no tenga tantos problemas al hacer un Instalador con las configuraciones del visual, le recomiendo que cree un cd, en donde se guarde todo los archivos e incluso pida y descargue las exenciones que haga falta. Puede probar usando este método: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWc5rEAcelY Espero sus comentarios a mi respuesta.

Comment: Estas queriendo hacer un instalador de winforms o un dll para compartirlo? Las firmas se usan para decir que es de una procedencia que la otra persona puede confiar. Podrias generar una firma y con esta misma firmar tus ensamblados. Aca tenes info de microsoft sobre las firmas https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2019

Comment: @RamiroBarone gracias, es una aplicacion de windows form, y vi videos que lo hacian con la opcion de publicar, pero cuando lo intente me aparecia el error de firma, por eso mi pregunta, igualmente vi otros videos que lo hacian desde el asistente de visual studio, pero queria saber que ventajas traia esa parte

Comment: El link que te deje no resolvio tus dudas?